# How to create a two dimensional list from imported data from text file

Tags: python, arrays, loops, text

I'm trying to import the info to create a 2D list, and I'm having a hard time filling in the list with the information.  I'm stuck trying to import the info to create the list

```
ROW = 3
COLS = 4
myInfo = ('myInfoFile.txt', 'r')
name = myInfo.readline().rsrip('\n')
while name != '':
    address = myInfo.readline()
    telNum = float(myInfo.readline())
    email = myInfo.readline()
myInfo.close()

list1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]

for r in range(ROWS):
    for c in range(COLS):
        #this is the main area
        list1[r][c] = myInfo
print(list1)
```

Comment: any sample of your text file?

Answer (score 0):

Two Things that are wrong

- You are not assigning the data while reading your file
- You are assigning a closed file descriptor while using your array
  Try This

      `info=[[]*COLS for i in range(ROWS)]
      for i in range(ROWS):
         for j in range(COLS):
             info[i][j]=filename.readline
             #if float needed
             info[i[[j]=float(info[i][j])`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a text file containing a 2D matrix, this works :

```
data_file = open('data.txt')
data = data_file.readlines()
for i in range(len(data)) :
    data[i] = list(map(float, data[i].split()))
print(data)
```

If you're using python2, drop the list argument in front of map.

Here are the contents of data.txt :

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Output :

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays in Python are dynamically sized, you can just use the `<list>.append()` function to add something to an array. Adding an array to `list1` allows a non-specified number of rows inside the matrix. Here is some modified code:

```
# The ROW and COLUMN variables aren't necessary.
myInfo = open('filetxt.txt', 'r')
list1 = [] # Not required to define the size of the array using zeros
while(True):
    name = myInfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if(name != ''): # Check for missing names
        address = myInfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
        telNum = float(myInfo.readline())
        email = myInfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
    else:
        break
    list1.append([name, address, telNum, email])

print(list1)
```

With the following test data, the output is: `[['Alice', '1 River Drive', 3.14159265, 'alice@example.net'], ['Bob', '2 Mountain Way', 127.001, 'bob@example.net'], ['Carl', '33 Oak Tree Avenue', 987.654321, 'carl@example.net']]`

with the following input:

```
Alice
1 River Drive
3.14159265
alice@example.net
Bob
2 Mountain Way
127.001
bob@example.net
Carl
33 Oak Tree Avenue
987.654321
carl@example.net
```